# Run SQL query for a specific time

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

How can run a sql query (insert into table) on oracle database for a specific amount of time (60Mins) in a loop.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample data, expected output as your question is not clear

Comment: may i ask what is the goal here. There are more efficient ways to load data, instead of a loop logic

Comment: I want to create a long transaction of almost 1 Hr, and for that i was trying to insert rows into a table without any commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

- note start date (time)
- exit the loop when certain amount of time has passed

I'm not going to wait for 1 hour, so I used 0.1 minutes = 6 seconds.

```
SQL> create table test (datum date);

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_mins_to_exit number := 0.1;   -- Exit in 0.1 minutes = 6 seconds.
  3                                    -- You'd put 60 in here
  4    l_start   date;
  5    l_minutes number;
  6  begin
  7    l_start := sysdate;
  8
  9    loop
 10      insert into test (datum) values (sysdate);
 11
 12      l_minutes := (sysdate - l_start) * 24 * 60;
 13      exit when l_minutes > 0.1;
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select min(datum), max(datum) from test;

MIN(DATUM)          MAX(DATUM)
------------------- -------------------
30.01.2020 12:57:07 30.01.2020 12:57:13

SQL>
```

As you can see, difference between `MIN` and `MIN` date really is `6` seconds.

How many rows did I insert?

```
SQL> select count(*) from test;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    448624

SQL>
```

I don't know what you are going to do; I hope you have enough space on a disk for millions of rows.